# Повторное распределение заявок между пользователями

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть пользователи и заказы. Я делю их равномерно между пользователями. (Первый результат в запросе) Как бы всё ок, нормально распределил. Но потом добавляются еще новые пользователи. И мне нужно сделать новое перераспределение. Но бывает такое, что пользователь сделал уже лимит по первому или новому распределению, в этом случаи я выставляю ему в колонку limit, значение из колонки made. Но алгоритм немного не верно работает и по факту он распределил 52 заявки, а их всего 50...

```
    declare @orderCount int
    set @orderCount = 50 --Orders for Distribution

    --Result table
    declare @t table (
    users char(3),
    limit int,
    Made int
    )

    --Add users
    insert into @t (users, limit, Made) values
    ('us1',0,0),
    ('us2',0,0),
    ('us3',0,0)


    --Table for the Distribution algorithm
    declare @c table (
        users char(3),
        limit int,
        Made int,
        Cnt int,
        Rn int
    )

    --Count users and row_number 
    insert into @c
        select
            *,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as Cnt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users) as Rn
        from
            @t

    --var for check new distribution>made
    DECLARE @check int = 0

    --Distribution
    update t
    set @check = (@orderCount/Cnt) + CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             limit=
                CASE WHEN
                    (@check >= t.Made)
                THEN
                    @check                  
                ELSE
                    t.Made
                END
            FROM @t t
                INNER JOIN @c cn ON cn.users=t.users  

    --Test data
    UPDATE @t SET Made=12 WHERE users='us1'
    UPDATE @t SET Made=10 WHERE users='us2'
    UPDATE @t SET Made=5 WHERE users='us3'

    --Check result
    SELECT * FROM @t

    --add to distribution new users
    INSERT INTO @t  (users, limit, Made) values ('us4',0,0)
    INSERT INTO @t  (users, limit, Made) values ('us5',0,0)

    --Clear table
    DELETE FROM @c

    --Check new data
    insert into @c
        select
            *,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as Cnt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users) as Rn
        from
            @t

    --Distribution
    update t
    set @check = (@orderCount/Cnt) + CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             limit=
                CASE WHEN
                    (@check >= t.Made)
                THEN
                    @check                  
                ELSE
                    t.Made
                END
            FROM @t t
                INNER JOIN @c cn ON cn.users=t.users            

    --Check result
    SELECT * FROM @t
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: Мне кажется вам надо распределять заявки между пользователями итеративно с шагом 30-60 сек (в зависимости от вашей сложности), получили Id свободных пользователей, получили Id незакрытых заявок, прошли, назначили по одной, поставили флаг что пользователь занят, следующий проход повторяет выше описанное. Так вы назначаете больше работы тому кто с ней справляется быстрее и распределяете все заявки.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov По сути этот подход мне не доходит, нужно делать распределение на лету. Пользователь может делать другой вид заказов(их несколько, порядка 20-40) и он может начать с любого. Но это я знаю как сделать. Тут суть проблемы в том чтобы перераспределить и он не получил больше заявок если при новом распределении у него сделано больше чем новый лимит. If newlim12 > made 15  then newlim=15. Найти всех у кого превышает новый лимит(сум) Вычесть из суммы и при распр. делить уже не 50 а 38/4. А этому выставить 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.users, 
        x.work,
        x.Made,
        sum(CASE WHEN Made>NewLimit  THEN  Made ELSE 0 END) OVER() as Dif,
        count(CASE WHEN Made<NewLimit  THEN NewLimit END) OVER() as Cnt,
        CASE WHEN Made>NewLimit THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsUsed,
        (CASE WHEN Made<NewLimit THEN
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.work, (case when Made<NewLimit then 1 else 0 end) ORDER BY work) ELSE 0 END) as Rn
FROM (
SELECT t.users ,(@orderCount/Cnt) + CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as NewLimit,
         t.Made,
         t.work     
    FROM @t t
        INNER JOIN @c cn ON cn.users=t.users
        ) x
```

Собственно и ответ на мой вопрос.